# Java Generate rainbow color - how?

Tags: java

I d like to show rainbow colors in java, so the color first time: red, then light red.. then orange light orange, yellow...etc..

How i can do this?

Comment: Which Java graphics API are you using? AWT? Swing? Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For rainbow colors I would suggets HSV (Hue-Saturation-Value) color space. For all rainbow colors just cycle through the hue.

Comment: yeah, i d like it:) any help on this?

Comment: Check out Color and ColorSpace classes. There's a default HSV ColorSpace defined, you just have to get its instance.

Comment: Sadly that's not correct... The HSV model wraps around the original colour, and rainbows do not go back to red after violet (they continue with ultra-violet).

Comment: Good catch :) Technically that's true, but I guess he's fine with the visible spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

A few hints:

- Find a function to transform the wavelength to RGB space [Convert light frequency to RGB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472514/convert-light-frequency-to-rgb)
- Overwrite the `paint` function of a component

  - Remap one of the coordinates (you choose x or y if you want to show the rainbow horizontally or vertically, or time if you want an animation) to visible light wavelengths.
  - Paint each line http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawLine%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29 (or rectangle with a width greater than 1px if you don't need the smoothest gradation) covering your component with a different colour, remapping the wavelength to RGB space.