# Map rainbow colors to RGB

Tags: java, rgb

Suppose I have a class RainbowColorsMapper with the constructor `RainbowColorsMapper(int n)`, where n>=2. Now I want to have continuous mapping of rainbow colors from red to violet which I get using the method `mapper.getColor(int number)` where low values correspond to red end, and high near n to violet end. If n = 2, `mapper.getColor(0)` returns most left color of the spectrum (near red), and `mapper.getColor(1)` returns the most right color. Same with bigger n with automatic scaling.

My question: can this be done relatively easy, and if yes what are suggestions on the algorithm?

Comment: Er: "RainbowColorsMapper(int n), where n>=2" and "mapper.getColor(1) returns the most right color"? What are you talking about, Willis?

Comment: What does "Same with bigger n with automatic scaling" mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to do this will be to work in the [HSL colourspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) rather than RGB. Create colours where the saturation and lightness are fixed (to 100% and 50%, i would suggest), and the hue varies between suitable endpoints (which you might need to experiment to find). Convert the HSL values to RGB using [Color.getHSBColor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getHSBColor%28float,%20float,%20float%29).

Comment: Yes, seems the easiest way. Thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the colours of the rainbow are ordered according to wavelength, so basically in your model, `n` is somehow related to wavelength. So your question essentially boils down to mapping wavelength (`n`) to RGB. This is not an entirely trivial process, but for a start, you could check this question out:

[Convert light frequency to RGB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472514/convert-light-frequency-to-rgb)

Comment: This would be the best option if mapping wavelengths wouldn't be so problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Or use a Hue Saturation Value color model, and iterate over Hue.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have a hue change from 0 to 300 in the colour model

[How to calculate RGB from Hue you can find on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue)

Answer (score 0):

[HSL Color](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/05/hsl-color/) allows you to do this easily.

Answer (score -1):

```
 private int r = 255;
 private int g = 0;
 private int b = 0;

 private void nextRGB() {
     if (r == 255 && g < 255 && b == 0) {
         g++;
     }
     if (g == 255 && r > 0 && b == 0) {
         r--;
     }
     if (g == 255 && b < 255 && r == 0) {
         b++;
     }
     if (b == 255 && g > 0 && r == 0) {
         g--;
     }
     if (b == 255 && r < 255 && g == 0) {
         r++;
     }
     if (r == 255 && b > 0 && g == 0) {
         b--;
     }
 }

 public Color nextColor() {
     nextRGB();
     return makeColor();
 }

 private Color makeColor() {
     return new Color(r, g, b);
 }
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but that way there are always two fixed values, so there will be no mid-tones, right? I mean `5,230,123`for example isn't possible...